# Logout from virtual console tty

Tags: linux

Having configured getty program in inittab file to autologin:

```
c2:12345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -a root 38400 tty2 linux
```

how can i logout from such a tty? When i switch to that virtual console (using `Alt+F2`) and type logout the console seems to re-login automatically.

Comment: Why `respawn` then?

Comment: You *do* understand what `-a` does, right?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams it just autolog a user specified? Isn't it?

Comment: Yes. Which is why you can't ever "log out" from it.

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski So should i change it to just `once`?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. If you want it to autolog just once, then yes. Note: I have not a bit of experience, I've just read the documentation.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams So what internally happens when i type logout i such autologin console?

Comment: One `agetty` terminates. Because of `respawn` another one is immediately run. It logs `root` in because of `-a`.